# Remainder in java isn't correctly calculating

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with my remainder function not properly calculating. I'm trying to write a program that tells the user what integers it's divisible by (2-9) after they enter a number. I'm having problems with this if statement always running no matter whether the number fits the condition or not:
    int five;

```
    five = digit % 5;

    if (five == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("This number is divisible by five!");
    }
    else {

    }

    System.out.println(five);
```

I also added a println statement, to see what five was coming out as, and when I entered the number 36, it was giving me a remainder of 0 which should be 1. I have also tried it with this formatting:
    int five;

```
    //five = digit % 5;

    if (digit % 5 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("This number is divisible by five!");
    }
    else {

    }

    System.out.println(five);\
```

And still having the same results.

Comment: We need to see more code. What is the *type* of `digit`?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] please?

Comment: [Looks like the if doesn't always run to me](http://ideone.com/NhjET1).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int remainder(int dividend, int divisior){
            int remainder = dividend%divisior;
            if(remainder==0){
                System.out.println("no remainder");
                return remainder;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Remainder is =>"+remainder);
                return remainder;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @bordia plz check above code and let is it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with java modulo operator, believe me. Try to set the `digit` variable manually and check the result, everything will be fine. Problem probably is that you enter the value from keyboard and convert it in some wrong way, thus changing the variable and at the same time - the remainder. If that's the case just use:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int digit = sc.nextInt();
```

Also, your second way is not gonna print anything, you don't initialize `five` anywhere.

Comment: I did initialize five, but Eran edited it out so it doesn't show up. I figured it out though. Stupid mistake on my part.